# Changing files metadata under Ubuntu WSL

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is it even possible?

According to this [blogpost](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/) :

> "*Windows file metadata is different from Linux file metadata. While
>   it’s the OS’ job to store and update your file metadata, most of
>   Windows doesn’t know anything about Linux, nor Linux file metadata,
>   and doesn’t automatically add or update Linux file metadata for all
>   Windows files because that would impose an unnecessary overhead on the
>   vast majority of Windows users who will never run WSL.*"

With Mac I could always use `touch -t YYYYMMDDHHMM file.jpeg` to easily change files creation date.

I've tried the same under Windows Subsystem for Linux. Yet it does nothing. Tried to `cd` into directory beforehand, yet also nothing. 
Tried to use `/mnt` and run it with `sudo`.

Is there a special syntax to be used when running WSL - Ubuntu? 
How would you **read** files metadata under WSL and then modify it?

Comment: WSL metadata are stored as NTFS extended attribute (in WSL1) which is different than normal Windows file metadata and can't affect each other. Normal File Explorer can not show it.

Comment: Could you explain a little more why do you need this? There are some options like for example, execute a windows command from wsl to change the file. So, knowing your use case will help to provide a better solution.

Comment: I am trying to change files creation date with 'bash'.  I know how to do it with PowerShell.  I just made a switch from mac to windows. I was thinking I would be able to use the 'bash' commands which I already know, rather than learning everything from scratch specifically for windows ;/ Oh well WSL aint that great then after all.

Comment: You can use Cygwin, msys2 unix-like environments. Or use a real Linux distro.